# std::ostream::operator<< not defined for std::string?

Tags: c++, std, stdstring, ostream

I have stumbled upon an error for which I cannot grasp the reason.

I think it basically gets down to this error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<<(const std::basic_string<char>&)’
```

I looked into specification on [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) and indeed it says there is no definition for `std::ostream::operator<<` with `std::string` as an argument.

My question is, what happens when one writes `std_ostream_instance << std_fancy_string;`. I believe it is one of the most common invocations ( e.g. `std::out << std::string("Hello world!")` ) next to `const char*`.

The error originates from these lines:

```
template<typename T> 
void Log::_log(const T& msg)
{  _sink->operator<<( msg ); }
```

`_sink` is defied as `std::ostream*`
There are some wrapping functions around but it breaks here.

I think I could work around by writing

```
template<> 
void Log::_log<std::string>(const std::string& msg) {
  _sink->operator<<( msg.c_str() );
}
```

since there is `ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const unsigned char* s );` defined by default.

I just see no reason why it is not guessed automatically since it clearly works in simple use like `cout << any_std_string`.

Not sure if this is relevant but I want to be able to pass down through my log functions anything than can be handled by `std::ostream`. I used explicit non-templated declarations but decided to move to template for `log(const T& anything_to_log)` to refacator it. It seemed plain stupid to have 5+ overloads. I get the error when I try compiling something like `Log::log( std::string("test case") )`.

It looks like something stupid-simple but I cannot get it on my own. Tried to google and search stack to no avail.

With regards, luk32.

PS. I checked the work-around and it works. Why it's not implicitly done ?

Comment: `std::string` has the `.c_str()` member function which converts to `const char*`.  Doesn't that work?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt
Maybe you could use something like `(*_sink) << some_arg` to pick up both member and non-member versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`operator <<` overloads are not members of `ostream`. They are freestanding functions, for example

```
ostream& operator << ( ostream& out, const basic_string<T>& bs );
```

Try

```
template<typename T> 
void Log::_log(const T& msg)
{  *_sink << msg;  }
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you. I thought that `ostream::operator<<()` would pick up globally defined versions. My fault. My problem was similar to such case `operator<< (*_sink, msg);`, where in turn compiler can't see definitions for `const char*` invocations. Your version picks up both.

Answer (score 5):

The `std::string` version is not a member function, so can't be called as a member of `_sink`. Try it this way to pick up both member and non-member versions (in fact it is unlikely you will need the member versions at all anyway):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ostream * os = &std::cout;
    std::string s = "Hello\n";

    // This will not work
    // os->operator<<(s);
    (*os) << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Or better yet would be to store `_sink` as a reference, and output exactly as you normally would to `cout`.

Comment: Thank you. Also good reference in the comment under the question. Another good example to your code would be `char* s2= "test2"; operator<< ( *os, s2);` which would fail. Only `(*os) << s` will pass both. hamstergene was 1st to answer so I accepted his. But this has good examples.